# removing filter with dplyr R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

What I am trying to do is filter for certain groups within a dataset then select the max success rate of the group where the N > 10 then remove the filter so that I can apply the outcome to all groups in the set.

```
results<-df1 %>%
  group_by(course, Race) %>%
  summarize(DI=sum(success), pct=sum(success/n()), n=n())%>%
  ungroup %>%
  group_by(course) %>% 
  #mutate(ref=max(pct[n>]))
  filter(Race == "White" | Race == "Asian" | Race == "African American" | Race == "Hispanic/Latino") %>%
  mutate(reference=max(pct[n>10])) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(di_80_index=pct/reference, di_indicator=ifelse(di_80_index < 0.80, 1, 0)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(course, Race)
```

This returns the max for the row where the condition of Race = White or Asian or African American or Hispanic/Latino and N > 10 is met, however it excludes all of the other races for the rest of the analysis. What I am essentially looking for is a way to bring back all the data that was filtered out and then apply the

```
mutate(di_80_index=pct/reference, di_indicator=ifelse(di_80_index < 0.80, 1, 0))
```

to the whole dataset. Instead what is happening is that only White, Asian, African American and Hispanic/Latino remain. I am basically looking for an "unfilter" to happen. Any thoughts?

edit: alternatively, if I could nest the filter(Race) within

```
mutate(reference=max(pct[n>10]))
```

somehow, then that would would solve the problem. Something like:

```
mutate(reference=max(pct[n>10] & Race == "White" | Race == "Asian" | Race == "African American" | Race == "Hispanic/Latino"))
```

Datasample:

```
Race = c("African American","African American","African American","African American","African American", "Asian","Asian","Asian","Asian","Asian", "Hispanic","African American","African American","African American","African American","African American", "Asian","Asian","Asian","Asian","Asian", "Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic", "White","White","White","White","White","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic", "White","White","White","White","White","African American","African American","African American","African American","African American", "Asian","Asian","Asian","Asian","Asian", "Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic", "White","White","White","White","White", "Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino","Filipino")
course = c("ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5","ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5", "ENG 8","ENG 1", "ENG 3", "ENG 5")
success = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)

df = data.frame(course, Race, success)
```

Comment: Need some example data ideally. If I understand correctly then an approach would be to first filter and calculate down to a single value and then use that value to calculate the results in the original data. There are other ways, but need the data for that.

Comment: You could probably get rid of the filter altogether and modify your mutate to be `mutate(reference = ifelse(Race %in% c('White', 'Asian', 'African American', 'Hispanic/Latino'), max(pct[n>10]), NA))`

Comment: The ifelse isn't working to provide the correct results, sadly

Comment: my original attempt was `mutate(reference=max(pct[n>10 & Race == "White" | Race == "Asian" | Race == "African American" | Race == "Hispanic/Latino"])` and i think it wasnt working because i didn't have the a ( before Race?? So far it looks like that code is working. I need to to a bit more testing.